# How do I insert cell Values instead of cell formulas?

Tags: excel, vba

Everything is working, except for the insert function. I can't figure out how to get it to insert the values from the "pull" file to the "put" file.

I'm getting the standard #REF in each "put" file cell when all I want is the basic text from the "pull" file (Not the formulas).

```
    Sub PullTally()
 pullFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="All Files (* . *) , * . * ")  'Copy From'
 putFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="All Files (* . *) , * . * ")   'Insert To'

Workbooks.Open fileName:=pullFile
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K4:M19").Copy

Workbooks.Open fileName:=putFile
ActiveSheet.Range("A100").Insert xlShiftDown

    MsgBox Pulled
End Sub
```

I have tried `.Value` but that obviously didn't work and I'm struggling to find anything helpful.

Comment: Maybe try `ActiveSheet.Range("A100").PasteSpecial paste:=xlValues`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to insert (not just paste) cells so the existing data gets shifted town you first need to insert empty cells and then `.PasteSpecial` the values only.

```
Option Explicit 

Public Sub PullTally()
    ' get source and destination workbook files
    Dim pullFile As String
    pullFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="All Files (* . *) , * . * ")  'Copy From'
    Dim putFile As String
    putFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="All Files (* . *) , * . * ")   'Insert To'

    'open source workbook
    Dim SourceWb As Workbook
    Set SourceWb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=pullFile)
    
    ' define range to copy from that source file
    Dim CopyRange As Range
    Set CopyRange = SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K4:M19")

    ' open destination workbook
    Dim DestWb As Workbook
    Set DestWb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=putFile)

    ' get a range of the size of the source range and …
    ' … insert empty cells
    DestWb.Worksheets(1).Range("A100").Resize(CopyRange.Rows.Count, CopyRange.Columns.Count).Insert xlShiftDown
    ' … copy source
    CopyRange.Copy
    ' … paste values into those empty cells
    DestWb.Worksheets(1).Range("A100").Resize(CopyRange.Rows.Count, CopyRange.Columns.Count).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    MsgBox "Pulled"
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting an Error: Runtime error 1004  PasteSpecial method of range class failed.

Comment: @Jakebnda sorry my bad of course there needs to be a `CopyRange` before you can `.PasteSpecial`. See updated answer.

Comment: Ok, it's inserting blank cells, and then pasting below those inserted cells, which is overwriting the data past A115. Im not sure how to get it to select A100 for the last bit of the code.

Comment: @Jakebnda well I didn't expect Excel to handle the `With` block so weird. Check my edited answer, that should work properly now.

Comment: I'm getting a runtime error 91 : Object Variable or With block Variable not set. It's highlighting " Set CopyRange = SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K4:M19")" when debugged.

Comment: @PEH I was able to get it to run by removing     Dim CopyRange As Range
    Set CopyRange = SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K4:M19")  and writing it out long form.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
Sub PullTally()

    pullFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="All Files (* . *) , * . * ")  'Copy From'
    putFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="All Files (* . *) , * . * ")   'Insert To'
    
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=pullFile
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K4:M19").Copy
    
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=putFile
    ActiveSheet.Range("A100").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    MsgBox Pulled
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Careful! This will overwrite the data past A100 and NOT insert new cells and shift existing data down!